# Using a trigger on a multi-row insert statement sqlite

Tags: sqlite, triggers, group-concat

I am working with a table that for the purposes of this question is defined like this

```
CREATE TABLE players (match_id, hero_id, player_slot);
```

This table is very frequently updated (a transaction every 20 minutes or so, with roughly 1000 inserts). It contains ~6 million rows atm, but will be constantly growing. I want to read (again, very frequently) the following SELECT statement from the up to date table.

```
SELECT t1.match_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(hero_id) AS team,
    COUNT(DISTINCT hero_id) AS team_size
FROM (SELECT match_id, hero_id
      FROM players
      WHERE player_slot in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      ORDER BY hero_id) t1
GROUP BY t1.match_id;
```

This is a pretty simplified version of the query, but it's still to slow for me to run every time I want an updated version. As such my hope was to set up a separate table and trigger on insert to the "players" table. Fortunately I will always be inserting all of the records with a given match_id in a single statement, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO players (match_id, hero_id, player_slot) VALUES
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 4, 4),
    (1, 8, 5);
```

I want to write a trigger that triggers on these inserts; ordering, and then grouping the rows inserted. I haven't found how to do this anywhere. It doesn't seem possible to get all of the rows being inserted as a single table on which GROUP BY and ORDER BY can be performed. Is there an efficient way to do this? If not is there a workaround that will be fast enough?

Comment: Your SELECT query is not valid SQL.

Comment: Missed a couple commas if that's what you are referring to. As I said, it is the gist of a much larger query, which I'm quite sure is valid because I've been using it.

Comment: You cannot have ORDER BY before WHERE, and it does not make sense in a subquery.

Comment: Ahh yes I flipped the order of those two. However ORDER BY absolutely does make sense in a subquery, as the order of the values returned by the subquery is the order in which they will be concatenated which effects the values of the returned table. Namely, in a later query I will be grouping by the "team" column, and I need teams to be equivalent regardless of permutations, hence the sorting before concatenation.

Comment: To elaborate, this is the reason I can't just make a column for each player slot and trigger an upsert on each inserted row. I need to order all of the hero_ids inserted in the multi-row insert and then concatenate them to get the correct team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query cannot be sped up by much; the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses conflict and cannot use the same index; and [rule 15](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening) prevents flattening of the inner query (which might have allowed the outer query to use some index).

---

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says:

> At this time SQLite supports only FOR EACH ROW triggers, not FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers.

So it is not possible to fill the cache table automatically; you have to update the cache from your code after you've written a `match_id`.

Comment: Yeah, I already went ahead and implemented a non-sql workaround in my code. Unfortunate that this couldn't be done automatically within the database. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: upvoted! newbie here, does this mean even when doing a single bulk insert, the trigger would be run for every row in the insert as opposed to the single operation that insert was?

Comment: @PirateApp The "ROW" in "FOR EACH ROW" indeed means "row", not "statement".